# My if for lowercase in a program that converts a person’s name from lowercase to uppercase or vice-versa isn't working

Tags: java

I am trying to make a java program that converts a person’s name from lowercase to uppercase or vice-versa. This is the code that I have so far. My problem is that the lowercase if statement doesn't work and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I'm new and this is the farthest I've gotten with working code. I'd like to keep the code simple, because this is about as much that I've learned so far. Also any advice on how to shorten this code is welcomed. Thanks

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChangeCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter your first name:  ");
        Scanner scanFirstName = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstName = scanFirstName.next();

        System.out.print("Display your name in uppercase(U) "
                + "or lowercase (L)?  Enter U or L:  ");

        Scanner scanChoice = new Scanner(System.in);

        String choice = scanChoice.next();

        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("u")) {
            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("l")) {
                String lower = firstName.toLowerCase();
                System.out.println("Your first name in lowercase is: " + lower);
            } else {
                String upper = firstName.toUpperCase();
                System.out.println("Your first name in uppercase is: " + upper);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry - must be U or L.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `choice.equalsIgnoreCase("l")` can never be true because it's checked only if `choice.equalsIgnoreCase("u")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modified your conditions.
Here is working code.

```
if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("l")) {
    String lower = firstName.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println("Your first name in lowercase is: " + lower);
} else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("u")){
    String upper = firstName.toUpperCase();
    System.out.println("Your first name in uppercase is: " + upper);
}
else {
    System.out.println("Invalid entry - must be U or L.");
}
```

The condition for Lower Case check

> if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("l"))

was nested inside condition for upper case. I just moved it out to make the two conditions parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Use this as your code.... Your If-else block modified...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChangeCase {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter your first name:  ");
    Scanner scanFirstName = new Scanner(System.in);
    String firstName = scanFirstName.next();

        System.out.print("Display your name in uppercase(U) "
                + "or lowercase (L)?  Enter U or L:  ");

        Scanner scanChoice = new Scanner(System.in);

        String choice = scanChoice.next();

        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("u")) {
            String upper = firstName.toUpperCase();
            System.out.println("Your first name in uppercase is: " + upper);
        }
        else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("l")) {
                String lower = firstName.toLowerCase();
                System.out.println("Your first name in lowercase is: " + lower);
            } 
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry - must be U or L.");
        }
    }
}
```